# ionic2 android build error

Tags: android, ionic2

When I try to run ionic 2 application

```
ionic run android
```

It stops leaving an error as below. Please help me to fix this problem

```
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

* What went wrong:
Task 'wrapper' not found in root project 'android'.

* Try:

Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.435 secs

Error: /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1
```

My ionic info is

```
    Cordova CLI: 7.0.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.2
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Platform list is

```
Installed platforms:
  android 6.2.3
Available platforms: 
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~4.1.0
  ubuntu ~4.3.4 (deprecated)
  webos ~3.7.
```

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't figure out what exactly went wrong. But did you try installing Gradle separately?

Comment: All I can see is it is missing the 'wrapper' task in the project root\

Comment: Yes I installed Gradle

Comment: can you provide the output of `cordova requirements` run in your project folder?

Answer (score 3):

Just figured out the problems,

I just remove Gradle and run below code

```
sudo apt-get remove gradle
```

And ran

```
ionic run android
```

Its install Gradle itself, The problem was solved

Comment: After following your advice I am getting this error
`Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android 
        Studio`

Answer (score 1):

I found the gradle executable in android-studio-path/gradle/bin and included it to my $PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the site https://gradle.org/releases, download the lastest version in some folder.
Unpack the zipfolder and create a symbolic link: sudo ln -sf /PATH-TO-BIN-FOLDER/gradle /usr/bin/gradle

Comment: what is the path added in PATH variable for gradle? I think we need to update /etc/environment. I am running build on Linux Mint 17

Answer (score 0):

are you using Jessie Debian or ubuntu this will be right,

1. go to https://gradle.org/install and  download the version 4.0
       of    gradle,
2. mkdir opt/gradle
3. unzip -d /opt/gradle    gradle-4.0-bin.zip
4. /* I using Debian Jessie then I do :

   ```
   if [ -d "/opt/gradle/gradle-4.0" ]; then
       export GRADLE_HOME="/opt/gradle/gradle-4.0"
       PATH="$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin"
   fi
   ```
5. open another terminal and type gradle -v
6. return to cordova project and type cordova build