# IONIC 2 : While deploying an IONIC app to android device : Task 'wrapper' not found in root project 'android'

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, ionic2

While deploying ionic app to android it's giving error as follows, It seems gradle is missing but when I check cordova requirements the gradle is installed. What's happening here?

```
auli@auli-H81H3-M4:~/ionic/iProjects/gplusauth$ cordova run android
ANDROID_HOME=/home/auli/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

* What went wrong:
Task 'wrapper' not found in root project 'android'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.385 secs
Error: /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1
```

and here is cordova requirements:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21,android-20,android-19,android-18,android-17,android-16,android-15,android-14
Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863744/ionic2-android-build-error

Comment: @SurajRao I think I have to update gradle to latest version. But I'm unable to do cause it's producing some error , do you know something about it :auli@auli-H81H3-M4:~$ sudo apt-get install gradle-4.3.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gradle-4.3.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gradle-4.3.1'

Comment: have you installed android studio?

Comment: @Suraj Rao Yes I Have.

Comment: then you could set the gradle home to the gradle installed with your studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue with upgrading gradle to latest version.

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-gradle-on-ubuntu-16-10